# setup.exe installer capture to msi with answer files for setup.exe

Tags: windows-installer, software-packaging

Complete new to msi packaging, just played a little bit with orca and a few repackagers for testing so that would be it.

I have a setup installer which I capture to a msi package.

Yet I want to provide the answer files/parameters for the setup either inside the msi or as external parameters to msi so that the msi passes these to the setup.exe.

I don't know what would be the best approach or even how to achieve that so I'm asking for advice. Maybe you can point me in the right direction.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It sounds to me like you want to wrap your setup.exe inside an MSI file and run the setup.exe as a Custom Action with your answer file as a parameter.  But I don't see the value in doing that.  You may as well just run the setup.exe from a cmd file or equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Advanced Installer setup packaging tool. They have a dedicated wizard for this operation; it is called a Response Transform and you can use it to save all the UI parameters into an MST file. But please note this is a paid tool.